# Getting records where column value equals an aggregate value of that column

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with several columns such as "pcode", "completion in %" and "pstatus".
For example:

```
pcode P_Name     completion  subordinate         pstatus
p123  inventory     10%         sanjay           progrssing  
p123  test          20%         komal            progrssing
p124  asd           20%         ritika           progrssing
p124  qwsdf         10%         asd              progrssing
```

I want to get result with different code with highest `complete%` with other column. All field are text. I'm using asp.net using c# and msaccess database.

What I'm looking for as a result is:

```
 pcode P_Name     completion  subordinate         pstatus
  p123  test          20%         komal           progrssing
  p124  asd           20%         ritika          progrssing
```

Answer (score 1):

On the database side, you'll have to filter your data. Following query should help you with that

```
SELECT t1.[pcode], t1.[P_Name], t.[completion], MAX(t1.[subordinate]) [subordinate], [pstatus]
FROM [YOUR_TABLE] t1
    JOIN 
    (SELECT [pcode], max([completion]) [completion]
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
    GROUP BY [pcode]) t
    on t.[pcode] = t1.[pcode] and t.[completion] = t1.[completion]
GROUP BY t1.[pcode], t1.[P_Name], t.[completion], t1.[pstatus]
```

*Note:* Concerning the `binding` part of your question, you'll have to provide more information if you're wiling to get (precise) answers.

Comment: thanks for reply but which type information u require pls tell me,when i execute ths query and it ask completion paraeter value name,in my tablecompletion is text type

Comment: i m using visual stdio 2008 with .net framwork 3.5.I m new i hav no more information in database

Comment: Are you developing a web application? A desktop application? Are you using an ORM or plain ADO.Net data access features? You'll have to help me a bit there...

Comment: web application and plain ado.net thanks budy

Comment: Last question: Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: Ask freely if u hav any query

Comment: @user1085240: I already did, but didn't get any answer: "Web Forms or MVC".